# How can I reference a column with a hyphen in its name in a pyspark column expression?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json document shaped like this (note that this schema isn't under my control - I can't go get rid of the hyphen in the key):

```
{
   "col1": "value1",
   "dictionary-a": {
      "col2": "value2"
   }
}
```

I use `session.read.json(...)` to read this json in to a dataframe (named 'df') like this:

```
df = session.read.json('/path/to/json.json')
```

I want to do this:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("col2", df.dictionary-a.col2)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dictionary'
```

How can I reference columns with hyphens in their names in pyspark column expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it, the hyphen in `df.dictionary-a.col2` is being evaluated as subtraction: `df.dictionary - a.col2`.

Instead, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.col`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col) to refer to the column by name and [`pyspark.sql.Column.getItem`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem) to access an element of the dictionary by key.

Try:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df2 = df.withColumn("col2", col("dictionary-a").getItem("col2"))
```